# Cannot fetch data with Vuex and axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

I create 2 projects - 1 for backend and 1 for frontend with Laravel and VueJS.
From Laravel i create API endpoint for all users:

Laravel `routes/api.php`

```
Route::prefix('users')->group(function(){
    Route::get('all', [UsersController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Here is `UsersController`

```
public function index(){
        $user = User::select('id','name', 'email')->get();

        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

and this is what i received from api with Postman:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Toni Stoyanov",
        "email": "toni.nikolaev.23@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Thomas Shelby",
        "email": "st3851ba@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

And this is my VueJS files:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://backend.test/api/'
```

and in my Vuex i made folder users/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    state(){
        return{
            users: {

            }
        }
    },
    getters:{
        getUsers(state){
            return state.users
        }
    },
    mutations:{
        SET_USER(state, data){
            state.users = data
        }
    },
    actions:{
        async setUsers(context){
            let response = await axios.get('users/all')
            console.log(response)
    
            context.commit('SET_USER',response.data)
        }
    }
}
```

and in my component with computed property:

```
getUsers(){
            return this.$store.getters.getUsers
        }
```

And nothing come into my app..When i fill users with some dummy data getter works, but actions and mutations doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to dispatch the action in created hook :

```
computed:{
getUsers(){
            return this.$store.getters.getUsers
        }
},
created(){
   this.$store.dispatch('setUsers')
}
```